# Bug/feature preventing renaming link preview

Tags: facebook, links

Before sharing a link on Facebook, I could click on the title of the link preview to rename it (the uppermost point [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/01/technology/personaltech/12-things-you-didnt-know-facebook-could-do.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) describes what I mean). But now I tried to do this and clicking on the title just opened the linked page. The old handy feature seems gone. Or is it just a bug? If it is a "feature", is there any other way to rename link preview with some awful pregenerated title?

EDIT: I observed this in a group and on my wall. This doesn't seem to be browser specific (tested on Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: This still works for me, where are you trying to share it? (Post on your wall? Comment? In Group? etc)